# Moving shapes in canvas with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Need help with my code so that it moves the rectangle in initializePlayer to move up, down, left, and right with the keyboard arrows?

```
function initializePlayer() {
G.context.fillStyle = "purple";
G.context.fillRect(300, 200, 20, 20);
G.context.beginPath(130, 130);
}

function playerMove(dx, dy) {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.addEventListener("keydown", keyEventHandler, true); 

}


function keyEventHandler(event) {
if (event.keycode == 38) {
(y - dy > 0)
y -= dy;
}
else if (event.keycode === 40) {  /* Down arrow was pressed */
if (y + dy < HEIGHT)
y += dy;
}
else if (event.keycode === 37) {  /* Left arrow was pressed */
if (x - dx > 0)
x -= dx;
}
else if (event.keycode === 39) {  /* Right arrow was pressed */
if (x + dx < WIDTH)
x += dx;
}
}

function render() {
drawRect(makeRect(300, 200, 20, 20, "purple"))

}
```

any and all help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

This code is very messy, format it! But there are also some bugs:

- Apply the **keydown event** to the window, not the canvas. Otherwise the event listener isn't carried out.
- You used `event.keycode`. This property doesn't exist! The correct property is `event.keyCode`.
- In `keyEventHandler` there is a statement that does nothing: `(y - dy > 0)` I guess you meant `if (y - dy > 0)`.
- To repaint the rectangle when a `keydown` event occurs, you should call `render()` at the end of `keyEventHandler`.
- `render` doesn't work because `drawRect` and `makeRect` don't exist. I expect that this is just a part of your code, but I don't see the sense in this anyway, as you use fixed coordinates? What about this:

  ```
  function render() {
      G.context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      G.context.fillStyle = "purple";
      G.context.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
  ```

If you have problems with debugging, I highly recommend you [Firebug for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/), but every browser also has a built-in console that can be opened with F12.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){keyEventHandler(e);},false);
```

instead of

```
canvas.addEventListener("keydown",keyEventHandler,false);
```

What's actually working/not working? I need more information to actually answer the question... :(

Comment: Obviously G.context is the 2d context of a `<canvas>` element. And your solution doesn't work.